# How to list all installed python package

Tags: python-3.x, pip

```
PS C:\Users\yashi\OneDrive\桌面\Python Projects> python -m pip list
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        20.0.1
selenium   3.141.0
setuptools 41.2.0
urllib3    1.25.7
```

`python -m pip list` works. However, it shows the packages installed in python 2.7. I'm using python 3.8.

I tried `python -3.8 -m pip list`, `py3.8 -m pip list`， `python3 -m pip list`, `py3 -m pip list`
But none of them work.

Comment: `python3 -m pip list` works just fine for me (Mac OS X). With what command do you usually start your Python programs?

Comment: Can `py -m pip list` or `pip3 list` work?

Answer (score 1):

When using `pip` (or actually any other Python script directly), it is important to make sure which Python interpreter is used. Usually it is obvious which Python interpreter is used when calling `pip`, but it also often happens that it is not clear. So in case of doubt, it is better to explicitly call the Python interpreter. Typically:

```
> python -m pip list
> # instead of 'pip list'
> python3 -m pip list
> # instead of 'pip3 list'
```

If there is still doubt, one could even go one step further and use the full path to the Python interpreter explicitly:

```
> C:\Path\To\Python38\python.exe -m pip list
```

Under Windows, there is a very useful tool called [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?#python-launcher-for-windows), that allows to somewhat simplify the work when multiple versions of the Python interpreter are installed:

```
> py -2.7 -m pip list
> py -3.8 -m pip list
```

An interesting read on the topic: [Brett Cannon's article "Why you should use `python -m pip`"](https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/)

Comment: @user8314628 Does that answer the question? Any clarification needed?